# How do I configure sublime to collapse single line indents?

Tags: configuration, formatting, settings, sublimetext3

When I have at least two lines indented, sublime allows me to collapse the code:

[image]
[image]

However, when I only have a single line, I lose that ability:

[image]

Is there a configuration option to allow collapsing single indents?
I can't seem to find any.

Comment: There's no option for that; it's indent based and hard coded to only pop up a  gutter fold arrow for 2 or more indented lines. However you can still use the keyboard shortcuts to fold such a function. See the `Edit > Code Folding` menu items for the possibilities and what the keyboard shortcuts are defined as for you.